# AWS Redshift cross account access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Different teams own different datasets. The goal I want to accomplish is to be able to query different sources owned by different teams (AWS accounts).

- Account A - Redshift
- Account B - S3
- Account C - My account

From my account I would like to:

1. Access data from Account B's S3 bucket using redshift spectrum
2. Access Account A's redshift DB.

I know how to do do part 1, how can I query cross account redshift (part 2)?

Answer (score 1):

The owner of the relevant Amazon S3 buckets in Account B should add a **Bucket Policy** that grants access to the IAM Role being used by Amazon Redshift.

From [IAM Policies for Amazon Redshift Spectrum - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-iam-policies.html#spectrum-iam-policies-cross-account):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Example permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::redshift-account:role/spectrumrole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: it is possible that you have set up security on the redshift external schema o table that maps the spectrum tables - you may want to check that as well.